# Can one combine Jordan-Wigner Transformation and Schwinger-Boson Representation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, bosons

Is it technically possible to map a fermionic problem with $M$ Orbitals to a bosonic problem with $2M$ orbitals by combining the Jordan-Wigner transformation with the Schwinger-Boson representation? The idea would be, doing something like this: Consider fermionic creation/ annhihilation operators $c_k,c^\dagger_k$, with the Jordan-Wigner transformation given as

$c_k=(\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}(-1)^{n_j})\,S^-_k$,  $c^\dagger_k=(\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}(-1)^{n_j})\,S^+_k$,

where $n_j$ is the occupation of the $j^{\text{th}}$ orbital. Is it valid to write down identities

$c_k=(\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}(-1)^{n_j})\,b^\dagger_k a_k$,

$c^\dagger_k=(\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}(-1)^{n_j})\,a^\dagger_k b_k$,

using the Schwinger-Boson representation $S^+_k=a^\dagger_k b_k$, $S^-_k=b^\dagger_k a_k$ or is this completely wrong?

Comment: My understanding is that it is correct, but useless as it is hard to adapt to most real-world models.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you maybe elaborate a bit on what you mean by it is hard to adapt to real world models?

Comment: I meant it is hard (or maybe even impossible) to express as a quantization of a classical field theory with relativistically invariant action

Comment: A similar idea can be used to diagonalise the Hamiltonian for a chain of hard core bosons. Hardness constraint precludes directly diagonalising, but you can map boson->spin->fermion using the Holstein-Primakoff and Jordan-Wigner transformations. This results in a chain of non-interacting spinless fermions which is solvable.

Comment: @jacob1729 I am not familiar with the concept of hard core bosons. Can you maybe give me some hints on what you mean by "hardness" in this context?

Comment: @ewf I just mean bosons with the additional constraint $c^{\dagger 2}=0$ such that two bosons can't occupy the same site.